# Rails query: get all parent records based on latest child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

An order `has_many` order_events.

An `order_event` is a record of the state of the order, e.g., `pending_approval`, `confirmed`, etc.

Changes to an order are tracked by creating `order_events`.

I usually get the current state of an order by doing something like: `order.order_events.last.try(:state)`.

I would like a query to get all of the orders with a given current state, e.g., all orders where the current state is `cancelable`.

I initially had a scope in the `OrderEvent` model:

```
scope :cancelable, -> { where('state = ? OR state = ?', 'pending_approval', 'pending_confirmation') }
```

and then a scope in the `Order` model:

```
scope :with_dates_and_current_state_cancelable, -> { with_dates.joins(:order_events).merge(OrderEvent.cancelable) }
```

and simply used the latter for other purposes.

The problem here is that it returns all orders that are currently or have in the past satisfied the condition.

What is the best way to get all of the orders that currently satisfy the condition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using a query like this:

```
scope :with_dates_and_current_state_cancelable, -> {
  with_dates
  .joins(:order_events)
  .where('order_events.created_at = (SELECT MAX(order_events.created_at) FROM order_events WHERE order_events.order_id = orders.id)')
  .where('order_events.state = ? OR order_events.state = ?', 'pending_approval', 'pending_confirmation')
  .group('orders.id')
}
```

A bit hard to read, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

A classic solution here would be to use Rails [enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).

Add this to your order model:

```
class Order
  enum status: [ :pending_approval, :confirmed, etc.. ]
  ...
end
```

The status can be changed by doing the following:

```
# order.update! status: 0
order.pending_approval!
order.pending_approval? # => true
order.status  # => "pending_approval"
```

No need for the `order_events` model.

To query all the orders that are pending approval:

```
Order.where(status: :pending_approval)
```

Edit:
Alternate solution when `order_event` has necessary columns.

Add a column to the `order_event` called `archived` which can either be set to 1 or 0. Set the default scope in the `order_event` model to this:

```
default_cope where(:archived => 0)
```

Assuming 0 is not archived.

Now, when you create a new order event set the old event to 1.

```
old_event = OrderEvent.find(params[:order_id])
old_event.update(archived: 1)
new_event = OrderEvent.create(...archived: 0)
```

Whenever you query for pending review like so:

```
OrderEvent.where(:status => pending_approval)
```

Only events that are not archived will be shown.

Comment: What if the `OrderEvent` model stores other information besides the `:state`?

Comment: You could create an order event record and change the status at the same time? Or migrate the other information into the order table.

Comment: You could also add a column to the order event called `archived`. When an order changes state (a new order event is created) Set the previous order event to archived. Then you could set the default scope to only show Order events that are not archived.

Comment: I actually use the enumerize gem in the `OrderEvent` model, which keeps track of order changes and timestamps. It is essentially a minimal state machine. I could add to the `Order` model a `current_state` column that just contains the current state. But this seems redundant since the state information is already maintained in the `OrderEvent` model.

Comment: I think the archived column in the order event is the way to go.

Comment: @userFriendly I agree. It might seem redundant when each event already has a time/datestamp, but it's going to make the queries quicker and the ruby logic cleaner. Maybe add it to your answer?

Comment: If I am going to add information, I might as well just add the `current_state` column to the `Order` model and query that model. Is the query that I was after more complicated or inefficient than I had imagined?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a query that might work. I didn't turn it in to `ActiveRecord` methods, but here it is:

```
SELECT t.order_id
FROM
  (SELECT MAX(created_at) AS created, order_id
  FROM order_events
  GROUP BY order_id) as t
INNER JOIN order_events
ON t.order_id = order_events.order_id AND
   t.created = order_events.created_at
WHERE order_events.state = 'whatever_state_you_want'
```

Comment: Here is one: `Order.joins(:order_events).where('order_events.created_at = (SELECT MAX(order_events.created_at) FROM order_events WHERE order_events.order_id = orders.id)').where('order_events.state = ?', 'pending_confirmation').group('orders.id')`. I am trying to clean it up a little.

Comment: It seems to work. I need to test it a bit. I am also trying to make the inner part more readable.